# Select boxes, disabling values based on values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a select menu, that gives the user some criteria options that can use to act as a filter on a search, the user can add as many filters as they wish, however at the moment the user can add the same filter more than once.

What I am wanting to do is, when a user selects a filter from the select box, the value gets added into a array, and then that option in the select box is disabled, is this possible with javascript & jquery?

Currently I have the following

**Code that creates a new filter select menu**

```
$('select.option').live({
  change: function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'distance')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/distance',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'height')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/height',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'appearance')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/appearance',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'education')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/education',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'children')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/children',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'smoking')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/smoking',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'drinking')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/drinking',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'politics')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/politics',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'religion')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/religion',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'ethnicity')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/ethnicity',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'work')
    {
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/work',
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as the name of `url` and selected option is the same you can try this:

```
$('select.option').on({
  change: function() {
        var element = $(this).val();
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/row/' + element,
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your HTML looks like, but I would make it look roughly like this:

```
<select class="option">
    <option value="distance" data-path="ajax/row/distance">Distance</option>
    <option value="height" data-path="ajax/row/height">Height</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then have the jQuery be (assuming there are multiple selects in one page and a filter can only be applied once per row):

```
$('select.option').live({
    change: function() {
        // get selected history or empty array
        var selected = $(this).data('selected') || [];

        // get selected option
        var $element = $(this).find('option:selected');

        // if selected option in history, return
        if($.inArray($element.val(), selected) return;

        // otherwise, add to history and save back into element
        selected.push($element.val());
        $(this).data('selected', selected);

        // query AJAX by using the data- attribute of the option
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + $element.data('path'),
            success: function(data) {
                element.parent().next('td.fillin').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what does var selected = $(this).data('selected') || []; do? $(this).data('selected'); is returning undefined.

Comment: @sico87: the first time through $(this).data('selected') will be undefined, so the `selected` var will be set to an empty array instead (`[]`) - the second time around it won't, so it will return the saved array of previously selected options.